# How do I calculate how many bits are needed to represent any negative value?

Tags: javascript, c++, binary, decimal, signed

I'd like to know if there's a calculation that allows me to get the number of bits that I need to store any negative (signed) value (such as -1, -255, -1324, etc.)?

At the moment I have implemented a function to calculate this for values greater and equal to 0:

```
calculateBitsNeeded = function (value) {

    if (value == 0) {

        return 1;
    }
    else if (value > 0) {

        return Math.floor(Math.log(value) / Math.LN2) + 1;
    }
    else {

        //TODO ...
    }
};
```

E.g.: If I have the number -38 I would need 7bits for storing (101 1010).

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Any number in JS stored in 64-bits format.

Comment: @hindmost: Yes, I know about that. But I'm writing an application that communicates with a C++ Server on a very low level base. So in fact I have to deal with ArrayBuffers etc.pp. and have to take care of my bits ;)

Comment: So your question isn't related to Javascript. Tag it with `C++`

Comment: Well, the question isn't related to any programming language in particular, it refers to IT and software in general. My App is build with javascript but anyway I've tagged it with C++ now as well... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming that you are talking about *integer* numbers**.

To answer your question, you have to understand that on all modern platforms, integers are either considered *signed*, or *unsigned*.

JavaScript doesn't actually supports integers, they are stored as floating point values.  However, a 64 bit floating point number can handle 53-bit integers with full accuracy, so it can easily handle the 16 bit integers that C uses.

I'm going to ignore those and limit my answer to 16 bit ints that you'd use to talk to C.

A 16 bit **Unsigned** bit integer can have the values of: `0 - 65535`

A **signed** integer can have the values of: `−32,768 to 32,767`

Under both encoding, the numbers `0 - 32,767` are stored the same way.  No difference in handling.

However, the numbers `32,768 - 0` are stored using a system called [*two's compliment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Bit wise, the numbers `-1` and `32,768` are the same.  `-2` and `32,767` are the same.

So, the easiest way to calculate the bits needed for a negative integer is to convert it to its signed equivalent.

Comment: It supports only 53 integers exactly? Or dir you mean all 53-bit integers?

Comment: 53-bit. Thanks for catching that.